# Building latex project in VS Code through command line

Tags: compiling, build-system, command-line, visual-studio-code

I would like to build a latex project from the command line on a build server. We write the most latex documents in Visual Studio Code with the LaTeX Workshop extension by James Yu.

I have managed to create a Docker setup that installs Visual Studio Code on a Ubuntu 18.4 image. But, I cannot figure out how to let Visual Studio compile the project from the command line.

Any help?

Comment: Why don't you use the latex binaries to compile the project without VSC involved?

Comment: Maybe, what will the approach be then?

Comment: I successfully used an instance of Jenkins to compile a book every night and push it back to Github. When everything was successful a blinkstick LED gave green, when errors occured it gave red.